# Cppcheck syntax error on Template class having a function with template paramter

Tags: linux, c++11, templates, opensuse, cppcheck

Anyone knows how I can fix this Cppcheck syntax error (no more information than "syntax error") or if it is a false positive (maybe due to options used), I looked at template tutorials and documentations and didn't find any similar usage, the code is:

```
template<typename T>
template<class Archive> // Here is the Cppcheck syntax error
void MyItemContainer<T>::serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ....
}
```

I'm using :

- g++ (SUSE Linux) 8.2.1 20180831 [gcc-8-branch revision 264010]
- Cppcheck 1.82 (this is the last available version on openSUSE Leap 15), I have successfully build 1.89 version but I cannot run it, with same parameters as I do with 1.82 version I have "cppcheck: Failed to load library configuration file 'std.cfg'. File not found" error
- Cppcheck command is: cppcheck MyItemContainer.h --force --platform=unix64 --enable=warning --xml-version=2 --verbose --error-exitcode=0 --std=c++11 --language=c++

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks to be a problem/false positive with CppCheck. The code uses the correct syntax to define a templated (on `Archive`) member function of a templated (on `T`) class. The use of `class` or `typename` in the template signature makes no semantic difference here (but maybe CppCheck stumbles over that? Something to try...).

It could  be that some preceding code is invalid and causes a syntax error in this location, but that seems pretty unlikely.

I can't find any useful mention of the word "template" in [the manual](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/manual.pdf). But given that CppCheck is still actively developed, you could consider building a small code sample reproducing this problem and submitting it to their bug tracker at https://trac.cppcheck.net/.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will add an exception in my ignore list (Cppcheck --suppressions-list option) for this one and try doing a small code that reproduces this to submit to them. NB: I would have upvote you but I have too few reputation :(

Comment: I am a Cppcheck contributor, so I know a bit of what is going on there. Especially regarding `templates` there have been made many improvements and fixes in the last time. So I guess this is already fixed in a newer version. If your code compiles with g++ then it is very likely that Cppcheck has an issue with the code. I really can recommend switching to a newer version. If you do not have a Trac account you can also post in the forum: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/

Comment: Thanks @versat, I actually have posted a discussion as suggested by Max Langhof, here it is: https://sourceforge.net/p/cppcheck/discussion/development/thread/8bb5c73341/